# Trying to install git in Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed Git using

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

after that when I try and run `git` I get

> -bash: git: command not found.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install git-all` or even simply `sudo apt-get install git`?

Comment: @RudiVerago no, it says -bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory

Comment: `whereis git` gives something? using `dpkg -L git-core` can you find executable?

Comment: @RudiVerago whereis git
git:
root@me:~# dpkg -L git-core
Package `git-core' is not installed.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: ok git-core is not installed. `sudo apt-get install git-core` again

Answer (score 28):

Just found in other source:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

This will install the latest stable git version. The Ubuntu's repository has the oldest one.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't install the package from Ubuntu itself, the git version will be 1.7.0.4

I recommend using my PPA as you will get the latest version, as I write this it would 1.7.11.1

To add my Ubuntu git repository to your system

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pdoes/ppa`

And then you can do `sudo apt-get install git-core`

For more info see my site : [Git Packages for Ubuntu](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/git-packages-for-ubuntu/)

Comment: Peter - thanks for your efforts - at the moment, it appears that your site no longer supports Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting error of the

```
sudo apt-get install git-core: command not found
```

After adding repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pdoes/ppa
```

then run this command which was still giving me same result.

`sudo apt-get install git-core`

But this command done all of things for me

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to #3 above. Command does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install git
```